# What does ADC SOC(start-of- conversion) in TI c2000 tms320f2802x devices mean?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, texas-instruments

I'm using TI C2000 f28027. In reference manual it's mentioned that this ADC is not sequencer based. Instead, it is SOC(start of conversion)based. What does that mean? Can anyone explain difference between sequence based and Start-of-conversion? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you show us where did you find this information? I cannot find anything like that in this manual: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruhh2c/spruhh2c.pdf?ts=1628761160844&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FLAUNCHXL-F28027

Comment: I found this in Technical reference manual.https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sprui09/sprui09.pdf?ts=1628766539695    You can find this in ADC overview part(page 403-404).

Comment: Ok then, It is what I thought. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

In many ADC sensors (lets pretend a temperature sensor) there are two modes of operation:

1. You send a signal to the sensor to start the conversion from Analog to digital, you wait for it to finish, and then you can read the information (the temperature)
2. You tell the sensor to do the conversion from analog to digital again and again, even if you are not reading it, and once you read it, you take the last conversion it did.

A similar example of this is the [MAX31865 ADC converter](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX31865-218546.pdf) IC sensor which reads temperature from a PT100/1000 and the MCU can read it via SPI:

[image: MAX31865]

At page 13 you can see the above, it says it can continuously convert, or convert upon request (1-shot conversion).

**EDIT**

As your datasheet states:

[image: TI C2000 f28027]

There is no mode for continuous ADC conversions. You will have to send a trigger for each conversion. SOC means you initiate a conversion, the ADC cannot start a conversion from its own.